# Upgrade a VS 2012 Sharepoint 2010 project to Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2010, 2013, upgrade, visual-studio-2012

I have a SharePoint 2010 Solution that is made in VS 2012.
I wanted to try and upgrade the solution to it deploy to our new SharePoint 2013 server.

In the Package properties i have set the version to 15.0

[image: Package.package properties]

The site url is pointing to the SP2013 site collection.

[image]

But the Server Connection is giving me the following error.

[image]

Also, the Project Properties, wont let me choose .NET Framework 4.0

[image]

How can i get VS2012 to treat the project as if it is a SharePoint 2013 Solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I should have checked this earlier.

I made 2 empty SharePoint projects. One 2010 and one 2013 and did a compare of the different files.

The only difference i could find was in the csproj file.
In the SP 2013 project there is a **<TargetOfficeVersion>15.0</TargetOfficeVersion>** property that was not present in the SP 2010 project.

I added it and reopened the project, and it worked just fine.

You could also change the TargetFramework to 4.5 but i chose to do it in the project properties instead, incase VS is doing something special when you change Framework

If you have references to the _layouts folder or the _controlltemplates folder, like you have in visual web parts, you should change them to _layouts/15/ and _controlltemplates/15/